# How to run the keycloak server in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper

I have a java application which is running in tomcat recently I have integrated keycloak security to the application.

Question: **How do we run the keycloak server inside the tomcat where I am running my application. So both are running in the same server with different ports**.

Comment: You can't.  Keycloak takes advantage of the full JEE stack and Tomcat is a servlet engine only.  The Keycloak distribution is built on Wildfly, a full JEE server.